# Como realizar la funcion de dos menús en el header en wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap, wordpress

[sitio de ejemplo](http://portafoliodemafia.com.ar/)Hola estoy haciendo un sitio donde necesito tener dos menús en el header uno para desktop y otro para mobile, el problema es que no se como realizar la función para luego poder administrar en el panel de wordpress. adjunto dicho código que implemente.

```js
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
 function register_mis_menus() {
   register_nav_menus(
     array(
       'principal-menu' => __( 'Menu Principal' )
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_mis_menus' );
 
function menu_posts_types () {
 register_post_type('paper-toys',
 array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __('Paper-toys'),
    'singular_name' => __('paper-toys'), 
   ),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-universal-access',
   'supports' => array('title','editor' , 'thumbnail','page-attributes'),
   )
 );
}
add_action('init' , 'menu_posts_types');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <a href="#main">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </a>

        <?php  
         $defaults = array(
            'theme_location' => 'principal-menu',
            'container' => 'false',
            'menu_class' =>'menu-wrapper'
            );

            wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
        ?>

            <div style="width:100%; float:left; position:relative">
                <div class="menu-button hide-l"></div>
            </div>
        
    </header>

    <div class="menu-mobile hide-l">
        <ul>
            <a href="#bio"><li>SOBRE MI</li></a>
            <a href="#galery"><li>TRABAJOS</li></a>
            <a href="#paper"><li>PAPER TOYS</li></a>
            <a href="#contact"><li>CONTACTO</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: una sería crear un menú responsive, que se adapte al tamaño de la pantalla (eso se haría mediante reglas CSS, usando media query); otra sería (en el caso de que quieras dos menúes distintos según el tipo de dispositivo), detectar por código el tipo de dispositivo que está accediendo y según el tipo, mostrar un menú u otro. La 1ª opción es la más fácil, y es como trabajan los temas modernos. Si lo de media query te suena a chino, debes saber que hoy día deberás usarlo, sea en una opción o en otra. Y no es tan complicado como podría parecer.